# Unexpected lines showing between images in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Firefox and Safari, the images on this page align tightly, but viewed in Chrome extra pixels display between the images.

Retain the HTML h1 tag, if it is removed the bug does not always happen.

**MAC OSX, Chrome 47:**

```
a horizontal extra pixel row displays at 67% zoom
```

**Windows 10, Chrome 48:**

```
both vertical and horizontal extra pixels show at 100% and all zooms
```

**Android Mobile Phones, any Chrome**

both vertical and horizontal extra pixels show at 100% and all zooms

**HTML**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chrome Bug Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #test-div img {
      float: left;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Chrome Bug Test</h1>

  <div id="test-div" style="width:720px !important; height=540px !important; overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png" />
    <img src="slice-div-test.png">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The above code looks good, and you might have the problem with images.

Comment: no, the images are fine.  I just double checked the page on Android mobile LG D851 using Chrome.  It's a problem with Chrome rendering

Comment: Can you post screenshot and highlight the problem?

Answer (score 0):

just add **vertical-align** to your images

```
img {
  vertical-align : middle;
}
```

and it will solve your problem

Comment: the 2nd image is a screen shot of the issue as seen in Chrome at 67% zoom.

Comment: `#test-div img { display:block; margin:0; padding:0; width:101%; height:101%; }`

Comment: this worked to get rid of the lines in both Chrome and Safari for desktop and mobile

Answer (score 0):

Setting css **object-fit** property will help:

```
img {
    object-fit:cover; //use contain if you do want it to 'fill up' the parent, but either value will solve your issue.
}
```